# php postgresql check if record already before inserting

Tags: php, postgresql, upsert

I cannot figure out the proper wording/syntax for the query statement. I want to check if there is a school already in our table (names schools) that matches the school name. If so, the state it already exists. Any input would be great!

```
  //create a connection (the connection is made in another php file)
  $obj = new MyConnection();
  $obj->setConn();
  $obj->displayValues();
  $qObj = new MyCode();
  $qObj->setConn( $obj->getConn());

  //Query to put all the school data into db
  $q1 = "INSERT INTO schools(
                 SchoolName,
                 SchoolWebsite,
                 City,
                 State,
                 Locale,
                 Sector,
                 Tuition,
                 GradRate,
                 FacToStudRatio,
                 StudentPop,
                 FreshmenPop,
                 PercentWomen,
                 PercentMen,
                 PercentAdmitted,
                 AverageGpa,
                 AverageScore)

        VALUES ('$SchoolName',
                '$SchoolWebsite',
                '$City',
                '$State',
                '$Locale',
                '$Sector',
                '$Tuition',
                '$GradRate',
                '$FacToStudRatio',
                '$StudentPop',
                '$FreshmenPop',
                '$PercentWomen',
                '$PercentMen',
                '$PercentAdmitted',
                '$AverageGpa',
                '$AverageScore')";


  $findResult = pg_query( 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE schoolname =.$SchoolName);

  if ($findResult != 0) 
  {
    echo "School Record Already Exists<br/>";
    die;
  }

  $qObj->setQuery($q1);
  $qObj->runQuery();
```

Comment: _side note:_  to check a `School Record Already Exists` i recommend you to use  `SELECT SchoolName FROM schools WHERE schoolname ='.$SchoolName` instead of  fetching all columns(avoid `*`)

Answer (score 0):

You have `'` missing in your code

```
$findResult = pg_query( 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE schoolname ='.$SchoolName)
                                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the ["upsert" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670) - it's an insert-if-not-exists. Doing this is harder than you'd expect and very prone to race conditions.

The best solution is always a `unique` constraint or unique index. Try the insert, and if you get an error, you know the row already exists.

The alternative is to `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` the table, so you guarantee nobody else can insert an identical row into it at the same time. That doesn't scale well though.